Would I have been out?
Context: I was at baseball practice on Wednesday and was running to 3rd base during a simulated game. The shortstop who had just gotten the ball threw the ball towards the third baseman, and I thought it was an out for sure. However, the throw went low and hit me in the back of the foot (I'm fine). I had not yet touched the base, but they let me stay in because "Well, it's a practice so it doesn't really matter too much." I got to wondering if I would've been out had it been a real game. Does the fact that the shortstop touched and threw the ball change the call? If I'm not out, is it an error on the SS?

At no level of baseball can a runner be put out by being contacted with a ball thrown by the defense (whether intentional or not).   The defense must make a proper tag, or on a force play, tag the base.
For MLB rules, this is covered by 5.09(b).   The actions described do not meet any of the situations under this rule, especially not 5.09(b)(4), which is being tagged while off a base.

A TAG is the action of a fielder in touching a base with his body
while holding the ball securely and firmly in his hand or glove; or
touching a runner with the ball, or with his hand or glove holding the
ball (not including hanging laces alone), while holding the ball
securely and firmly in his hand or glove. [...]

Since the ball struck you in the back while running, it seems unlikely that anyone would suggest that this was intentional interference on your part.   But in a case where someone moves at the last second and is struck, they could be called out under 5.09(b)(3) for intentional interference with a thrown ball.
It is possible for a member of the defense to pick up the deflected ball and complete the tag properly if you have still not yet reached the base.

is it an error on the SS?

Maybe.   If the scorer believes that the out would have been made with a reasonable throw, then an error would be appropriate.

Makes sense that they wouldn't call interference. The ball, as I mentioned, was behind me. Had no idea what was about to happen until- bam!
